# how to put policy on emails sent through php/mail scripts in linux

Tags: linux, postfix

when an email is sent through network or email authentication using some mail client, it will surely pass through postfix smtpd and we will be able to track/put policy/ and add restrictions to it, but how the emails from the scripts can be tracked? as they do not pass through spmpd..

Is there any way to catch those emails and put restrictions on them? as many scripts on my server try to send lot of spam, with hundreds of domains.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `PREPEND` value; see the [postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html).
A few examples are [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/193456).

Comment: i dont have any control over the script, i just want all the emails from ANY script to go through postfix

Comment: php, perl, python, any script.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an identifier on the headers, you can add an authentication to send the mail, you can use a special FROM sender for each script or each site... There is a lot of possibilities. It depends of the numbers of scripts and who launch them, if you can modify the scripts or the website.

Comment: i dont have any control over the script, i just want all the emails from ANY script to go through postfix